# Using Jaxb Marshalling how can I override the XML Element names at runtime

Tags: spring, jaxb

In my code I have a class which is populated from a REST CALL like so:

```
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    String JSONStr = restTemplate.getForObject(urlStr, String.class);
    Gson gson = new Gson(); 
    Products items = gson.fromJson(JSONStr, Products.class);
```

Then later I write the the list as XML

```
         JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ProductsList.class);      
     Marshaller productMarshaller2 = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
     productMarshaller2.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
     OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("xml\\products.xml");

     for (int index = 0; index < items.size(); index++){
            System.out.println("Index = " + index);
         ProductsList productList = items.get(index);    
         productMarshaller2.marshal(productList, outputStream);
     }
     outputStream.close();
```

This all works great and provides the expected output. The problem I have is that the JSON that I get has field names like "atr_203948" and I need to place them with names like "color" - but can not know the mapping between the names ahead of time. At runtime I have to execute a DB lookup to get the current map. The DB look up is easy and I have code that creates a HashMap with the oldName,newName pairs but I do not know inject that knowledge into the output of the Marshaller. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have the feeling that JAXB might not be the right tool for this and you might need to write your own XML seriliser. Maybe using Xerces SAX interfaces and replacing those keys for the attribute name you get from the DB.

Comment: You could try to use [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJAXBAnnotations) instead of the JDK default JAXB Libraries, to handle your (de)serialization. It is very flexible and able to handle also complex use cases, because it can present your information either as typed object graph or as untyped tree of nodes.